# How can I validate a text box, which should only allow characters A-Z & a-z, not integers nor special characters

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to validate a text box in html, where user will enter his first name, and input do not accept integers & Special Characters?

```
<input name="txtfname" type="text" maxlength="30" required />
```

Comment: <input name="txtfname" type="text" maxlength="30" required />

Comment: With HTML `pattern` attribute, JS form validation or PHP $_POST validation ? There is a lot of way to do it and you tagged everything ...

Comment: (Aside: What if my first name is André?)

Comment: `<input name="txtfname" type="text" maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+"/>`

Comment: thanx,,, and to allow integers only which pattern will be mentioned in txt box.

Answer (score 3):

Try this javascript code for validation

```
function Validate() 
{
    var val = document.getElementById('your_input_control_id').value;

    if (!val.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) 
    {
        alert('Only alphabets are allowed');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to check the username field on both the client and server side.

Javascript:

```
var username = document.getElementsByName("txtfname")[0].value;
if (username .match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) {
    // Valid
} else {
    // Invalid
}
```

PHP:

```
$username = $_POST['txtfname'];
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+$/", $username ) {
    // Valid
} else {
    // Invalid
}
```

Comment: This script is to accept Alphanumeric values. That is it will return true, even if there are numbers in the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
  In Javascript 
  var uname = document.form.username;   
   function validate(){
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
    if(uname.value.match(letters))  
    {  
    return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
    alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
    return false;  
    }  
    }
    In Html 
    <form method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return validate();" name="form">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="username"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper RegEx.

The only punctuations that should be allowed in a name are full stop, apostrophe and hyphen. This RegEx will also work for names like André.

**^[\p{L} .'-]+$**

```
var username = document.getElementsById("fname").value;
if (username .match(/^[\p{L} \.'\-]+$/)) {
    // Valid username
} else {
    // Invalid username
}
```

Comment: But JavaScript regular expressions don't support Unicode character classes.